# Python Get Request Loop

Tags: python, request

hopefully there is a kind soul out there which will offer to graciously answer my question as I continue my learning experience.

I have written the following simple python code to bring back a sporting web site I would like to scrape.

I want to be able to scrape from race-1 to race X without having to manually change the url. So I was wondering is it possible to include a loop to scrape all races from 1 to end and consolidate in one print file.

```
import requests

url = "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2018-01-01/flemington/sectionaltimes/race-1.json?callback=sectionaltimes_callback"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string formatting to insert the current race number into the URL.

```
import requests
payload = {}
headers = {}

for race in range(1, X+1):
    url = f"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2018-01-01/flemington/sectionaltimes/race-{race}.json?callback=sectionaltimes_callback"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    json_string = re.sub(r'^sectionaltimes_callback\((.*)\)$', r'\1', response.text)
    data = json.loads(json_string)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar I have made your suggested changes and get the following error msg "name 'X' is not defined". So I am not sure whether you have placed "X" as just a generic symbol for me to include the relevant field or there is something missing.

Comment: You said you wanted to go up to race X. I assumed you had defined `X`. Use whatever variable you want for the limit.

Comment: Haha sorry my mistake - works a treat. Thank you

Comment: Would it be possible to ask for your further help in getting this into a JSON format. You helped answer a similar question because the output comes back as JSON with padding. Now that I am calling back multiple events that padding appears throughout the string just not at the start. So I don't think the previous re.sub() coding solution fits anymore. The string starts with:   sectionaltimes_callback({"Horses":[{"Comment" and the sectionaltimes_callback function is embedded at the start of each race result.

Comment: Yes, the same solution works here.